# Naming conventions for neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, naming-conventions

Are there any standard naming conventions for neural networks? I am new to programming neural networks but have noticed a lot of consistency across tutorials and books and would like to get familiar with the naming conventions but can't find any sources. An example is that 'X' is usually capitalised and 'y' is lowercase for datasets. Some other terminology below.

```
NB_EPOCH = 200
BATCH_SIZE = 128
VERBOSE = 1
NB_CLASSES = 10
N_HIDDEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about naming conventions of neural network *frameworks* and *libraries* (e.g. Keras, PyTorch, Caffe etc), the answer is generally **no**.

Keras itself is a good example case, where the parameter name for the number of epochs changed from `nb_epoch` in [Keras 1](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#training) to `epochs` in [Keras 2](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#sequential-model-methods) (causing enough headaches in the transition...). [MXNet](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/model.html) uses `num_epoch`, while lower level libraries, such as Tensorflow and PyTorch, do not use epochs at all (notice that in PyTorch there are still [complaints](https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/issues/26) for confusion between using 'epoch' and 'iteration' in the tutorial texts).

It is true that, say, `batch_size` (in lowercase), tends to be standard (`verbose` too, but this is a much more general parameter, and not confined to neural networks).

So, in principle, you should not expect cross-platform compatibility in the naming conventions of the parameters.